# Как вывести путь к последним картинкам через gallery modx revo

Tags: modx, gallery, изображения, revo

Как вывести путь к последним картинкам через:

```
[[!pdoResources? 
    &sortby=`id`
    &class=`galItem`
    &limit=`1`
&tpl=`tpl`
]]
```

шаблон tpl

```
<div class="grid_4 box-2">
    <a href="[[+image_absolute]]" class="magnifier"><img src="[[+thumbnail]]" alt="[[+name]]" [[+image_attributes]] style="width:370px;height:250px;"></a>
        <div class="inside">
            <div class="text-3"><a href="[[~61]]">[[+name]]</a></div>
            <div>[[+description:ellipsis=`100`]]</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что есть "путь к последним картинкам"? У Вас `limit=1`, следовательно выводится одна картинка. Дополните вопрос (редактировать) какого результата Вы хотите добиться, что получается на данный момент.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Вопрос - вывести нужно последние картинки из компонента "Gallery"?

Answer (score 1):

В вызове [pdoResources](http://docs.modx.pro/components/pdotools/snippets/pdoresources) у Вас не указан `&includeTVs`, которое должно в себя включать имена дополнительных полей, которые требуется выводить (в Вашем случаи это `thumbnail,image_absolute,name,image_attributes`). Также значением `&tvPrefix` по умолчанию является `tv.`. Соответственно и в чанке `tpl` требуется выводить значение доп. полей с этим префиксом. Примерно таким образом: `[[+tv.image_absolute]] [[+tv.thumbnail]]...`